# Android: Official YoutubePlayer giving Network Error when playing a shortened URL

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm using the official Android YouTube player in my android app, it works well with full youtube URLs but it gives an error `Network Error` when the URL to play is shortened like this one `https://youtu.be/xxxxxxxxxxx`

Anyone know how to fix that ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: i'm using this pattern to extract the ID:

`(?<=watch\?v=|/videos/|embed\/)[^#\&\?]*`

Answer (score 0):

Use this one :

```
"http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html"
```

I use in javascript, i think it'll work the same for android.

Cheers.